# How to set environment variables in github actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

I'm trying to set and environment variable that is Used by my tests on github actions. I'm trying to achieve this as follows

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Test and Lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DEBUNKBOT_TEST_GSHEET_SHEET_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.DEBUNKBOT_TEST_GSHEET_SHEET_CREDENTIALS }}
    steps:
      - name: Run tests
        run: make test
```

The tests fail since they can't find the
`DEBUNKBOT_TEST_GSHEET_SHEET_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For setting `secrets.DEBUNKBOT_TEST_GSHEET_SHEET_CREDENTIALS`

In **gitgub.com**, go to the **repo** >>> **Settings** >> Click **Secrets** >>

Create **New secret** >>

**Name**
: DEBUNKBOT_TEST_GSHEET_SHEET_CREDENTIALS

**Value**: input the value of `DEBUNKBOT_TEST_GSHEET_SHEET_CREDENTIALS`

**Add Secret**

in `steps` :

```
env:
        set-env: DEBUNKBOT_TEST_GSHEET_SHEET_CREDENTIALS=${{ secrets.DEBUNKBOT_TEST_GSHEET_SHEET_CREDENTIALS }}
```

p/s : you should have Administrator role for that repository.

Comment: I have set this and from the logs, I can see the secrets. It's just that trying to read it from the test script doesn't work.

Comment: for github-action yaml environment, it should be define first ?

Comment: Adding this prevents the action from being executed. I'll play around  with it and see but I think this is the right direction

Comment: this didn't work. I think the environment variable might be set but I'm not able to read it using python

Comment: set-env has now been retired from github actions due to security issues (since this answer)